# In a metric space a sequence with no converging subsequences is discrete (?)

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

I've been trying to prove that given a metric space $X$ (**not necessarily complete**) and a sequence $(x_n)_n \subseteq X$ which contains no convergent subsequences, there exists an open neighborhood $V_n$ of $x_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that these $V_n$'s are pairwise disjoint i.e.:
$$
\exists V_1 \in \mathcal{v}_{x_1}, \ldots, \exists V_n \in \mathcal{v}_{x_n}, \ldots:
\forall n_1 \neq n_2: V_{n_1} \cap V_{n_2} = \emptyset.
$$
So far I am stuck trying to prove it by contradiction. All I've managed to see is that it wouldn't be enough to consider balls of the **same** radius around each element of the sequence, as this wouldn't prove anything for the sequence $(1+1/1, 1+1/2, \ldots, n+\frac{1}{n}, n+\frac{1}{n+1}, \ldots)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, which doesn't have any convergent subsequences. So I'm trying to work with the general hypothesis by contradiction:
$$
\forall r_1, \ldots, r_n, \ldots: \exists n_1 \neq n_2:
B(x_{n_1}, r_{n_1}) \cap B(x_{n_2}, r_{n_2}) \neq \emptyset,
$$
but I am stuck.
Obviously, I could just pick for each $x_n$ a radius small enough $r$ so that $B(x_n, r)$ doesn't intersect some balls $B(x_1, r_1), \ldots B(x_{n-1}, r_{n-1}), B(x_{n+1}, r_{n+1}), \ldots$, because if that weren't posible, it would mean the sequence would have a converging subsequence to $x_n$. But the problem is, I can't guarantee that the balls obtained this way also don't intersect each other, not just $B(x_n, r)$.
I feel like there is something important I should be observing here, but I can't see it. Also, in case you happen to know that this result isn't true or even better, you happen to have a counterexample, it would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty close.  As you noted, you can find radii $r_n$ such that $B(x_n, r_n)$ does not contain any other $x_k \ne x_n$.  Now consider the balls $B(x_n, r_n/2)$.  By a triangle inequality argument, you should be able to show that these balls are pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 4):

For each $x_i$ in the sequence, consider its distances from the other points in the sequence. Define the numbers

$$d_i=\inf_{j\neq i}\{d(x_i,x_j)\}$$

If this infimum was 0, then we could find a subsequence converging to $x_i$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, we know that each $d_i$ must satisfy $d_i>0$. Consider the collection of balls

$$\mathcal{B}=\{B_{d_i/2}(x_i)\}$$

Can you show that these balls are disjoint?

Answer (score 2):

If you assume the $x_n$ to be pairwise distinct, it can work. If $x_1 = x_2$, you are going to have trouble finding $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can prove it for complete metric spaces, here's how to proceed for non-complete ones. Let $X$ be the given (non-complete) metric space and let $\overline{X}$ be its completion. Then $(x_n)$ is also a sequence in $\overline{X}$, and you can find open subsets $V_i$ of $\overline{X}$. With the desired propreties. Now the sets $V_i \cap X$ are open subsets of $X$ with the desired propreties.